# videoView with seekBar, seekTo with seekBar progress

Tags: android, synchronization, android-videoview, seekbar

Now The seek bar moves according to the flow of the videoView. But I have a hard time with developing seek bar touch.

- This is what I want to develop.
  When I touch seek bar scroll, video view plays the part that matches the position of seek bar.

Under is my codes.

```
public class PreviewingActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {

private static final String TAG = "PreviewingActivity";

private ImageView playBtn, pauseBtn;
private VideoView recVideo;
private String videoPath;
private SeekBar seekBar;
private boolean isSeekbarTouch = false;
private Handler updateHandler = new Handler();

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_previewing);

    playBtn = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.play_btn);
    pauseBtn = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pause_btn);
    recVideo = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.rec_video);
    seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seek_bar);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    videoPath = intent.getStringExtra("recVideoPath");
    recVideo.setVideoPath(videoPath);

    playBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            recVideo.start();
            playBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            pauseBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });

    pauseBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            recVideo.pause();
            playBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            pauseBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });

    recVideo.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            playBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            pauseBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
    });

    recVideo.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            seekBar.setProgress(0);
            seekBar.setMax(recVideo.getDuration());
            updateHandler.postDelayed(updateVideoTime, 100);
        }
    });
}

private Runnable updateVideoTime = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        long currentPosition = recVideo.getCurrentPosition();
        seekBar.setProgress((int) currentPosition);
        updateHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
    }
};


@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean b) {

}

@Override
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
}

@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

}
}
```

If you know how to solve this issue, please let me know. Thank you for reading this question!

Comment: using seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener is more friendly than implementing SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this method

```
SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean b

if(b) {
 // Mean that the seekbar value is changed by user
  videoView.seekTo((progress*duration)/100); // Verify this
} else {
 // Ignore becuase is due to seekBar programmatically change
}
```

Comment: I did it already. But It's not works because handler keep affecting to seek bar I think.

Comment: setYour max seekBar to 100 as my example compute using percent